# Querying many times with Entity Framework mixes the results

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an instance of the entities and I am trying to query the database 2 or more times with the same instance.

```
myAppDbEntities db = new myAppDbEntities();
List<user> usersList = db.users.Where(c => c.userid == usrID).ToList();

foreach (user u in usersList)
{
    u.items = db.items.Where(c => c.userid == u.id && c.date == today).ToList();
    item extraItem = db.items.Where(c => c.userid == u.id && c.date == yesterday).FirstOrDefault();
    //...
}

return usersList;
```

The problem is, when the usersList is returned, that extraItem is being included with the user's items list.

All data that I am fetching as if is being appeneded to one another.

Thanks

Comment: If you comment out the 'item extraItem' line does it still happen?

Comment: No, if i don't use the "db" to query anything else, the result is as i want it to be.

I also noticed if i reinitialize the db = new myAppDbEntities(); it also works.

I'm worried if that is the right way of doing it? To reinitialize the db instance before every new query.
@EricScherrer

Comment: I'm stumped, but as a side not weird things like this is why I usually  do not return EF objects out of my resource access but rather use a framework like AutoMapper to return DTO's instead.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this - are there any foreign key in the database between users and items?

Comment: I suspect u.items is a pointer to whatever entities are loaded into the items collection for that user id. So if you load it from the db it will exist in the u.items collection. That's what I recall from my EF days, verifying now.

Comment: True. I figured that out also. If you query using the same context the collected data will appear to all variables you fill, that's if based on the Foreigh Keys.

The solution is to query with AsNoTracking() for the specific variable you want to be independent. @EricScherrer

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about AsNoTracking, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a foreign key defined between users and items, usersList is a pointer to myAppDbEntities.users, so no matter what you fetch from the db beforehand, if you go to a user and ask for it's items Entity Framework is going to go to the DB and get you all its items, unless you give it a filter at that time.

In order to stop this behavior and explicitly control what entities are loaded you must [Detatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach.aspx) the entity from the context. Here is the code example I used to test this behavior using EF 6.0:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parents = GetParents();

        foreach (var parent in parents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Parent: " + parent.ParentId);

            foreach (var child in parent.Children)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Child: " + child.ChildId);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Parent> GetParents()
    {
        var context = new EFTestDBEntities();

        var parentList = context.Parents.Where(x => x.ParentId == 1).ToList();

        foreach (var parent in parentList)
        {
            // Commenting out the following line makes the above Console.WriteLines enumerate all children
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Detach(parent);
            parent.Children = context.Children.Where(x => x.ChildId == 1).ToList();
        }

        return parentList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use AsNoTracking() for the query that you want to be independent:

```
myAppDbEntities db = new myAppDbEntities();
List<user> usersList = db.users.Where(c => c.userid == usrID).ToList();

foreach (user u in usersList)
{
    u.items = db.items.Where(c => c.userid == u.id && c.date == today).ToList();
    item extraItem = db.items.Where(c => c.userid == u.id && c.date == yesterday).**AsNoTracking()**.FirstOrDefault();
    //...
}

return usersList;
```